# Not work variables in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My context dictionary not sending to my templates. 
I have function

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
def home(request):
  return render_to_response('home.html',{'test':'test'},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and i have simple template such as:

```
<html>
<body>
my test == {{test}}
</body>
</html>
```

When i open my site in browser, i have "my test == ".
settings.py is default. I dont use something custom. What the problem?
Server is apache with wsgi module.

Comment: does it work using the django built in dev server?

Comment: Use the `{% debug %}` template tag to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: You didn't define what test is ` test = 'hello world' ` and in return `  'test': test  ` not `  'test':'test'  `.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the changes to the view?

Comment: @Goran it does not matter. the key `test` in the dictionary has the value `test` which is perfectly fine.

Comment: server not my, but when i change my html file, i get new page in browser. so, changes are accepted maybe. But tag {%debug%} is working.

Answer (score 0):

I know, but I see your post just now. You did great, but you need something more to do. Here is the view

```
def home(request):
    # You need to retrieve something from the database or create a variable here
    test = Test.Objects.all()
    # Use Context Dic
    context = {
    'test': test,
    }
    # Then Use the return
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

(EDITED)
Now this will work.